# SQL Server database isn't shrinking

Tags: sql-server-2019

I have a SQL Server database with a lot of unused space. However when I run Tasks | Shrink | Database And Tasks | Shrink | Files from Management Studio, it isn't freeing up any space.

Unfortunately the disk that it is running on is running out of hard disk space. Any ideas on why this space isn't freeing up?

Also recovery mode on DB is set to simple and database is on single user

[Disk usage report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeO8n.png)

[Database Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqLQk.png)

[Simple recovery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INitg.png)

[Single user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKpxq.png)

I deleted most of the tables on this database and it didn't change anything. Tried running `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` unsuccessfully as well.
Does anyone have any suggestions to recover that unused space?

Comment: Thank you Aaron. That is exactly what I'm doing. I transfered all other tables data to another database but in the last one, an 82GB size table, I can't transfer due to disk space. To transfer I used Import/export tool

Comment: Hi Aaron. I  think the best way will be to assign a new disk. I was avoiding it but seems it will be the best way. Thank you.